# Multiple motors with digitalWriteFast

Tags: list, arduino, int, constants

I try to use the library digitalWriteFast to control multiple motors and encoders. The library is only working with pins defined as const int. A minimal example I'm working on looks like this:

```cpp
// digitalWriteFast from:
// https://github.com/NicksonYap/digitalWriteFast
#include <digitalWriteFast.h>

// setup for motors
const int m_1[] = {A0, A4, 23, 24};
const int m_2[] = {A1, A5, 22, 25};

void motor_setup(const int id) {
  pinModeFast(m_1[id], OUTPUT);
  digitalWriteFast(m_1[id], HIGH);

  pinModeFast(m_2[id], OUTPUT);
  digitalWriteFast(m_2[id], HIGH);
}

void motor_forwards(const int id) {
  digitalWriteFast(m_1[id], LOW);
  digitalWriteFast(m_2[id], HIGH);
}

void setup() {
  motor_setup(0);
  //motor_setup(1);
}

void loop() {
  motor_forwards(0);
  //motor_forwards(1);
}
```

The code is compiling with one motor only. If you uncomment the lines `//motor_setup(1);` and `//motor_forwards(1);` it is raising the error:

```
Call to 'NonConstantUsed' declared with attribute error:
```

I have tried to use classes first, but I am not able to pass the const int to the instances. Any ideas on this topic?

Comment: I have no idea about arduino, but it looks like half of the error message is missing? Usually something follows after a colon. If there is something missing, can you please add it and format the error message as code. That is more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately the error message is ending at this point. (Even with advanced error messages enabled)

Answer (score 1):

`digitalWriteFast` needs to be passed a *compile-time* constant. While your `1` passed to the `motor_setup` and `motor_forwards` functions is a compile time constant, the parameter `const int id` is still a variable and so the accesses to `m_1[id]` and `m_2[id]` are variable also.

Comment: Yes, this sounds correct. I have not found a solution to pass the variable. I solved the issue by writing a function for every motor separately. This is no elegant way, but it's working ;)